# How does WPF handle CollectionChanged events for custom collections?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a few custom classes that wrap/represent collections which I want to use for WPF data-binding. The minimum requirement I could determine was that the class needs to implement `IEnumerable` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

While putting together the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` for raising the `CollectionChanged` event, I was wondering what to use for `newIndex` and `oldIndex` since my class doesn't support `IList` and has no indexing capabilities.

That brought me to my question:

If the classes do not implement `IList`, will the WPF framework when listening to `CollectionChanged` ignore the action and always react as if the action was `Reset`? If not, how do they do it (and what should I use for `newIndex` and/or `oldIndex`)?

Comment: why dont' use ObservableCollection?

Comment: Doesn't it depend on how you trigger the CollectionChanged event in your class? What value will you set as the [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.action(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: @ThierryV: One example is a class wrapping a `ConcurrentDictionary` to implement an "ObservableConcurrentDictionary".

Comment: @ZevSpitz: I would like to be as specific as possible (so that WPF does as little as possible), but the question is: would WPF care, if my class only implements `IEnumerable` (and not `IList`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is WPF will listening to `CollectionChanged` and act accordingly even the collection didn't implement `IList` interface. WPF will map data collection to its view(s), and a view always create a `IndexedEnumerable` wrapper to ensure that it can access the collection through an index. So, if you bind a collection to a WPF implemented dependency property like `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, you don't need to implement `IList` to let `INotifyCollectionChanged` work. But if you bind a collection to you own property, instead of using the source directly, you should create a view by using `CollectionViewSource`.

Comment: thank you! the sourcecode (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/IndexedEnumerable.cs) was very enlightening!