# Who uses NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs' features?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifycollectionchanged

This is a follow-up to my question, [How does WPF handle CollectionChanged events for custom collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555658/how-does-wpf-handle-collectionchanged-events-for-custom-collections).

According to Alex.Wei's answer (and the source code of [IndexedEnumerable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/IndexedEnumerable.cs,9cf420126aa99ebe)) WPF ignores the specifics of the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` (e.g. `Action`) and always reacts the same, ultimately as if `Action == Reset`.

So my questions: Who uses `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`' features and, if I raise the event manually (for a custom class) does it make sense to specifiy the details (if they are never evaluated)? Also, why does WPF behave like this - isn't this a potential performance killer?

Comment: *"does it make sense to specifiy the details?"* - it doesn't hurt to implement the interface correctly instead of relying on an event consumer not looking at the details. You can't be sure that one day WPF won't do.

Comment: @Clemens: in general, of course, I agree, but in my specific scenario (wrapping a dictionary that is not indexable) implementing the full details would be quite a pain, if even feasibly possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry if I didn't make things clear in last anwser. Actually, WPF behaves according to specifics of the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` like it means to be, and `IndexedEnumerable` just a tool that let `CollectionView` or other componets of WPF access to the source collections that didn't implement `IList` throngh an index easily. For example, after you bind a collection to `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, the things in below will happen.

1. `ItemsControl` will specify the collection as the source of its `Items` property.
2. `Items` property which is an `ItemCollection` will obtain a `CollectionView` by calling `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultCollectionView` method.
3. The view will try to subscribe `CollectionChanged` event of the source collection and act accordingly.
4. `ItemCollection` will also subscribe `CollectionChanged` event of the view and act accordingly.
5. And also, `ItemsControl` subscribe `CollectionChanged` event of the `Items` and act accordingly form the beginning.

So, the answer to you questions is that a lot of WPF classes are using `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`' features and you definitely need to riase `CollectionChanged` event correctly by providing all the details whatever you collection was implemented `IList` or not.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that WPF is going to raise an exception if you provide wrong indices or multiple elements in an `Add` or `Remove` action.

Apart from that, there is a range of frameworks (NMF Expressions, BindableLINQ, ContinuousLinq, Obtics) that make use of these CollectionChanged events in order to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` on queries. These frameworks will heavily rely on the details that you put in the event, despite you can of course always resort to a reset event.

Comment: If I'm not using any other frameworks (except WPF), then I may as well just always use `Action = Reset`. And: any insights on _why_ and the potential performance hit?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library. That library uses NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs very widely.